# Why is modus ponens a q-implication?

Tags: logic

Modus ponens is stated
$$((P \implies Q) \land P) \implies Q$$
But isn't $(P \implies Q) = (\lnot P \lor Q)$?

Then we get
$((P \implies Q) \land P) \implies Q$
$= (\lnot P \lor Q) \land P$
$= (\lnot P \land P) \lor (P \land Q)$
$= \text{False} \lor (P \land Q)$
$= P \land Q$
So $P\land Q$, not just $Q$. Why do we say that modus ponens then just implies $Q$?

Comment: It also implies $P\wedge Q\wedge True$, but we don't say that either.

Comment: We say that it implies $Q$, not that it implies only $Q$.

Comment: $P\implies (P\land Q)$ is equivalent to $P\implies Q$. “If this is a ruby, then it is red” is equivalent to “If this is a ruby, then it is red and it is a ruby”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, $P$ and $Q$ are both implied by $P$ and $P\to Q$.   In fact, $P$ and $Q$ and $P\to Q$ are all implied by $P$ and $P\to Q$.

However, we're *most interested* in learning new things.   $Q$ is new thing we learn from knowing $P$ and $P\to Q$.   It is not the *only* thing, but it is the *new* thing.

It is *useful* to know this, so we give the rule of inference a special name: "modus ponens".